# Multiple image selection in rails 3

Tags: jquery, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In one of my application, i have implemented multiple image selection option where a user clicks on browse button and selects a image. if he wishes to add more image clicks on add more image link, the form partial is appended to the div and again the same process repeats.

Is there a way when a user clicks on browse button and selects multiple images by holding "CTRL" and depending on the number of images selected the same number of fields get added.(Like in facebook).

Comment: there are numerous uploader like plupload, jquey file upload, amongst best ones.

Comment: @abhi jquery file upload was the one which i was looking for... thanks a lot

Comment: no probs anil, glad could help.